# JSTL doctype without internet connection

Tags: jstl, doctype

I was using a properties.xml file which i stored with java.util.properties storeToXML.

but storeToXML always set a doctype like:

```
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
```

now i use JSTL XML to check for the properties:

```
<c:import url="${settingsPath}" var="xml" />
<x:parse xml="${xml}" var="doc" />
<x:choose>
    <x:if select="$doc/properties/entry[@key='foo'] = 'true'">
      <!-- do something -->
    </x:if>
</x:choose>
```

but I want to use this without an internet connection.
but then i get the error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: java.sun.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A usable workaround might be to replace the doctype property by the proper doctype after the xml data has been generated.